# Example lesson code not compling

Tags: java, variables, methods

Hello I have and assignment which tells me to run this java code below,
But I keep getting 3 similar error say the variable studentInfo cannot be resolved to a variable

here's the errors

Error: studentInfo cannot be resolved to a variable - line 11
Error: studentInfo cannot be resolved to a variable - line 15
Error: studentInfo cannot be resolved to a variable - line 15

```
    public class DisplayInfoExersice {

        public static void main( String [ ] args ) {

             int studentInfo [ ] [ ] = { {1, 78, 85}, {2, 83, 90} };

             display( studentInfo );
        }

        public static void display( int array [ ] [ ] ) {

             for ( int j = 0; j < studentInfo.length; j++ ) {

                 System.out.println( ); 

                 for ( int k = 0; k < studentInfo[j].length; k++)
                       System.out.print ( studentinfo [j] [k] + "\t"                         
                  );
            }

            System.out.println( );
       }

   }
```

please help.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add the error messages *as text* to your question. Also indicate *which lines of code* are triggering the errors.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

// This is the correct version.

```
public class DisplayInfoExcercise {

    public static void main( String [ ] args )
    {
        int studentInfo [ ] [ ] = { {1, 78, 85}, {2, 83, 90} };

        display( studentInfo );
    }
    public static void display( int array [ ] [ ] )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < array.length; j++ ) //
        {
            System.out.println( );

            for ( int k = 0; k <array[j].length; k++)
                System.out.print ( array[j] [k] + "\t" );

        }
        System.out.println( );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You named it `array` in the `display` method declaration. Easiest fix change

```
public static void display( int array [ ] [ ] )
```

to

```
public static void display( int studentInfo [ ] [ ] )
```

You could also rewrite the entire program with lambdas in Java 8+ like

```
int[][] studentInfo = { { 1, 78, 85 }, { 2, 83, 90 } };
System.out.printf("%n%s%n",Stream.of(studentInfo) //
        .flatMapToInt(IntStream::of) //
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf) //
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\t")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using local variable studentInfo declared on main function, inside your display function. You are passing this variable as a parameter. You need to use the name of that parameter:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < array.length; j++ ) //

for ( int k = 0; k < array[j].length; k++)
System.out.print ( array[j] [k] + "\t" );
```